# Vim: Ignore but show pattern with errorformat?

Tags: vim, errorformat

My compiler generates errors on the common `file:line:column message` format, but my problem is that my test output includes a lot of time strings which matches this pattern. For example:

```
2013-01-01 01:23:00 Starting test foo
```

Is treated like an error in file `2013-01-01 01` on line `23` and column `00` with message `Starting test foo`.

I can filter out time strings using `%-G` and a regexp in the errorformat string, but that also removes the line from the quickfix window.

Is there a way to make `cnext` and `cprevious` skip lines matching a pattern (treating them as not-valid) but still include them in the output?

Answer (score 0):

That's tough. I would modify my `'makeprg'` and either use a script wrapper or directly append a post-processing step (e.g. with *sed*) that defuses the dates (e.g. by replacing the `:` with a `_` when it's surrounded by decimals).